# App linking doesn't trigger in outlook email

Tags: c#, android

I've followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking) tutorial for app linking. It works great. I created a basic site and when I clicked a button, it triggered the app linking.

The next thing I wanted to do was trigger app linking when viewing through outlook/gmail.

When the button is clicked, nothing occurs, it goes straight to the link. May I ask why does that occur? Does App-linking not work in emails?

My current Code

MainActivity.cs

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
DataScheme = "https",
DataHost = "dev.mytestsite.com",
AutoVerify =true)]
```

Website/email anchor tag

```
<a href="https://dev.mytestsite.com/"> CLICK ME </a>
```

One thing I noticed when I examine the html code is that the anchor tag gets other attributes added to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a trailing `/` being added when clicking a link in an email. See if the following works:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
DataScheme = "https",
DataHost = "dev.mytestsite.com",
AutoVerify =true),
IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
DataScheme = "https",
DataHost = "dev.mytestsite.com",
DataPathPrefix = "/",
AutoVerify =true)]
```

Comment: Same outcome unfortunately

Comment: Can you try removing the trailing slash in your email link?